# Document database as RDBMS replacement

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql, couchbase, rdbms

I'm planning to use NoSQL as primary database for all my application's data primarly because of terms like "scalability", "cloud", "big data" in mind. I don't care about "schema-less" as I use ORM frameworks anyway with traditional RDBMS.

Almost every application use relations, whether it is social network, e-commerce or something else there are always relations.

So I looked up different types of NoSQL databases that could qualify.

- <s>**Key-Value**: Definitely not for this purpose.</s>
- <s>**Column-based**: I rejected it immediately because it just looks unnatural to me and I will never use it</s>
- <s>**Graph-based like Neo4j**: They claim it's good for relations but it's just a clickbait and misses a lot of features that make me want to just use RDBMS after all. And some people only use it for geo search, and still use RDBMS for the main data. Apparently read performance is bad so I reject it.</s>
- **Document-based like MongoDB, Couchbase**: Seems like the most popular alternative for RDBMS (to replace it completely). Also MongoDB will be ACID compliant soon (https://www.mongodb.com/transactions).

Now the question is can something like MongoDB, Couchbase be used in scenarios with many relations(almost every application) as a complete replacement for RDBMS?

After like few days of reading about NoSQL and various use cases in big sites I came into conclusion that these databases are almost never used as primary/main databases and most often are used in connection with RDBMS for doing just some specific things.

Is it even valid to compare NoSQL and SQL databases considering ambiguity of this term?

SQL databases are not ambiguous while NoSQL databases are!

Good article that I found!: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/nosql-without-multi-document-multi-statement-transactions/

> The promise of NoSQL is speed; but like a car without brakes, not very safe unless it allows multi-document transactions.

--

> if you want to be taken seriously as a database, you need to support multiple statement transactions.

Comment: What are you asking here? All RDBMS's are, at some level, a complex query engine sitting on top of a hash-map store. A nosql database, then, by this definition is omitting much of the extra stuff RDBMS's bring to the hash-map base. The question is, do you need the extra stuff? Most people find they can get along better without it.

Comment: @theMayer I don't know if I need extra stuff. I'm staying with RDBMS. I can solve scalability problem with clusters or something else. Many people say "it depends" but in real world example you NEVER know what will you need in the future, maybe you will need "extra stuff" for something. To me all this NoSQL shit is just a hype and it's overrated.

Comment: I prefer to keep technology stack simple. I don't want 5 different things for 5 different purposes. Most of the sites on the internet use standard RDBMS, and they work fine.

Comment: I got rid of it because I was spending more time optimizing queries than I was developing my business logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `NoSQL` as a primary database but it would depend on what you would like to do with the database. For example, we use `MongoDB` as primary database but that's only because we never have to create complex transactions that would require a sophisticated isolation.

Whereas you can do things like multi-statement single transactions in most SQL databases, it is difficult to do so in `MongoDB` and probably in many other `NoSQL`. To start off with, `MongoDB` doesn't support multi statement single transaction at all and if you really need to emulate it, you will have to create a separate collection that would 'control' transactions. (As in looking into each transactions and modifying the targets in the other collections because atomicity and isolation is preserved in a single document level). It's something that is very much overlooked especially in small projects.

So can the `document` database replace `RDBMS` completely? No, but it has other benefits that complements the downside of `RDBMS` such as being very flexible and especially being serverless ready.

But can it be used as primary database? Yea in some cases but as your DB logic gets more complex, it would be a much better idea to use `RDBMS` because you just don't have to worry about `ACID`

Comment: ACID might not be a problem with MongoDB 4.0? Or it's just overcolored?

Comment: @lll yea sure but who knows. I can't say about what hasn't yet been released officially. But most `RDBMS` did have this feature mounted on them for a very very long time so even if `MongoDB` supports it this year, the stability and consistency would need to be checked. If your team likes to be experimental (personally I am quite so too), try out the `Mongo 4.0` but on more conservative side? just go with `RDBMS` where you don't have to think about any of these

Comment: Let's suppose one day you'd want to support something that requires transactions and you use database that doesn't support them, how would you solve it? Emulation as you describe?

Comment: The best way would be to just switch to a db that supports it I think. But if that is out of options then there are still ways to solve such a problem even without transactions. Because a single document modification is atomic, you can create transactions collection where you first mount all the transactions as documents (they would have status:'pending' or 'done' or w/e and task to be done). Then you change status of one transaction to proceed with the task and disallow any other threads from trying to process it.

Comment: it's better explained here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: Thank you! There's also [NewSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NewSQL) term  that I'm interested in recently but it seems immature

Comment: If Mongo 4.0 would come out it would become a bit like a NewSQL then? Except it's, still not relational so probably not, but close to that!

Comment: @lll yea sure but again I can't really say for what hasn't been released yet